# Customizing K2 admin panel

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, administrator, k2

I would like to hide/show specific fields in the K2 article editing panel for specific users.

[image: K2 article editing sidebar]

I would like to hide all the "item view options in category listing" and only show the image size selection in the "Item view option"

My first thoughts would be to duplicate the admin template and add `display:none;` to everything I want to hide in the CSS.

I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

I am using Isis admin template and joomla 3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did :

1. duplicated the isis template and asigned the duplicated template to the target users.
2. Created a template override for the com_k2 item in `/administrator/templates/isisCopy/html/com_k2/item/default.php` and deleted the unwanted fields in that file.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know k2 doesn't really make that easy to hide the extra stuff clients don't need. Wish they did, that would elevate it above CCKs. The other option is to css hide stuff.

Comment: @REactionFaye I agree, it would be great to get those options in K2. I also used CSS hidding for other things but I prefered using template overrides as much as possible.